# How to export XML of webpart on the page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I want to export the Web part XML based on GUID to the local. I am trying to export from SharePoint 2013 using CSOM PowerShell. Anyone suggest on this?

```
function EnsureDirectory($exportFolderPath)
{
  if ( -not (Test-Path $exportFolderPath) ) {New-Item $exportFolderPath -Type Directory | Out-Null}
}
 
function ExportAllWebParts()
{
  $WebURL= ""
  $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebURL)
  $Page = $ctx.web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("")  
  $ctx.Load($Page)  
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $wpManager = $Page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
  $webparts = $wpManager.Webparts  
  $ctx.Load($webparts)  
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

   if($webparts.Count -gt 0){  
    Write-Host "Looping through all webparts"  
    foreach($webpart in $webparts){
        $exportPath = "" + "\" + $webpart.Title + ".xml"
        $xwTmp = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($exportPath,$null);
        $xwTmp.Formatting = 1;#Indent
        $wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart, $xwTmp);
        $xwTmp.Flush();
        $xwTmp.Close();

        #$webpartXmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($fileName,$null)
        #$webpartXmlWriter.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
        #$wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart,$webpartXmlWriter)
          
        
        }  
              
    }  
}
ExportAllWebParts
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working in your current code. If you have error messages, paste these into the question in full.

Comment: cannot find an overload for "ExportWebpart" and the argument count: "2". At C:\:24 char:9 + $wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart, $xwTmp); + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: please check the error message: i will get error exactly on #$wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart,$webpartXmlWriter)

Comment: Would [this](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2018/01/sharepoint-export-web-parts-using.html) help?

Comment: this is server side.. can we get in the CSOM or PNP that will be really helpful to me